# CSS positioning with scrollable full size images

Tags: css

I'm new here and I hope someone can help me.

I've seen this site and wondered if anybody could help to make that in CSS. 
I have a header and underneath a Container wiith the content. What I don't get is how to tell the Image to always fill the screen even after resizing the window and how to tell the content to show as soon as you scroll.

Resize the Window in height and in width and scroll, to see what I mean. I would be grateful for any help.

cheers and TIA

[Sample Page](http://www.alpenhof.co.at/)

Comment: Add `background-size:cover;` to your `background-image`

Comment: That's called `responsive design`.

Comment: Hi and THX - the problem is, that the position is not fixed and it only covers the whole background till you scroll - with :cover the image always covers the screen. And it is not a background image, but a normal image...

Comment: Ok.. just a question: Don't the CSS codes: background-size:cover;
background-position:center center; only work on background-images? This seems to be a gallery and therefor differnt images for ervery page...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to set the height and width of the document (`body`) to the height of the viewport (`html`), get both to 100% and remove any margins to ensure content fills the visible space.

Then, you need to create your first area and give it a `background-image` and use `background-size:cover` and `background-position:center center;` so it becomes responsive- resizing when you resize the window.

Any subsequent content sections, need to also be given a height and width of 100% so they then scale relative to the visible area.

You can do this using, e.g. the below:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/vmLvx4hc/)

HTML

```
<header></header>
<section>Content</section>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
header {
    background:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQOrSSvhefLVAXo3OOoMGYGS232bfHFnZyA9Jk24KeefYuau8c);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
header, section {
    height:100%;
}
section {
    background:lightgrey
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewport width and height to always make the image fill the window:

```
#YourImage {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
```

It is also a good idea to set the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Furthermore, set the margin and padding of the document to Zero.

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Hope this helps.